# How can I pass data to URL in swift 3

Tags: php, swift3, phpmyadmin

I want to pass data from swift to phpmyadmin by php using GET.

---

**problem:**

I do not understand that how can I pass data to URL.

I'm having a php file URL(example) [http://aawebserver.ddns.me/swiftToPhpmyadmin/getData.php?
data1=xxxxx&data2=xxxxx](http://aawebserver.ddns.me/swiftToPhpmyadmin/getData.php?%20data1=xxxxx&data2=xxxxx) , I want to pass data to `data1` and `data2` of the URL from swift coding.

What is the coding for pass data to the URL?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "pass data to URL"? Do you want to include variables from your Swift code in the URL as query parameters? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is string then use below code

```
func addData(data1 : String ,  data2 : String) {
    let stringUrl = "http://aawebserver.ddns.me/swiftToPhpmyadmin/getData.php?data1=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2
    print(stringUrl)
}
```

And call this method and pass your string arguments like below

```
self.addData(data1: "Data1", data2: "Data2")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func addData(data1 : Any ,  data2 : Any) {
    let stringUrl = "http://aawebserver.ddns.me/swiftToPhpmyadmin/getData.php?data1=\(data1)&data2=\(data2)"
    print(stringUrl)
}
```

And call this method with arguments as below :

```
self.addData(data1: "data1", data2: "data2")
self.addData(data1: "data1", data2: 2)
self.addData(data1: 1.0, data2: 2)
```

Comment: How to run the URL?

Comment: `let url = URL(string: addData(data1: "data1", data2: "data2"))!   
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {   
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)   
    } else {   
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)   
    }`